# Visual studio 2022 IntelliSense only displaying for 1 second and then dissapearing

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2022

When i'm typing code, the intellisense comes up to predict code, but before i can choose something  in the list, its already gone. I know that you can use crtl+spacebar to bring it back up. But it's pretty annoying.
Does someone knows how to fix this?

(I'm using visual studio 17.3.1 (.Net - C#))

Comment: 1. If you have some extensions installed in Visual Studio try to disable them. 2. Try to Reset all settings under Tools>Import and Export Settings. 3. If these don't work, you can choose to repair or reinstall VS.

Comment: 1. did not work
2. did also not work
3. did the trick ! Thanks !

Comment: I just found out, what causes this:
i have auto save extension installed, and it was set to 1 sec, after the autosave, the intelliSense dissapears.
its now set to 15 seconds instead. Not perfect, but at least not so annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that this problem is caused by vs extension. You can try to disable the extensions and try again. If it doesn't work you can choose to reinstall Visual Studio.